# Project Architecture on Github

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-submodules

My question is more related to fundamentals. In my project, I need 2 decisions to make.

The first one is that I have 3 modules and I want to keep them inside separate repositories, and one of them is core module, and mod1 and mod2 depends on this. How can organize this structure in Github that changes in the core module deployed automatically to mod1 and mod2?

The second part is even more complicated and can change based on the first one(I guess). Since we are using Mod1 and Mod2 repo to directly use for deployment on Azure, someone from other teams will use this base repos to deploy for different customer, but we want to also keep this repos under same organization and keep the connection between for example mod1 and mod1-project1. Because some of the modifications in the projects can be bring back to the main repository Mod1.

Also we have the copy of core module inside Mod1 and Mod2 to deploy it with github actions but for example a change in core of the Mod1-project1, can be brought back to the core module since they don't have direct connection?

```
core-->mod1-->mod1-project1

mod1-project1-->mod1-->core
```

how can we maintain this relationship in a logical manner?

Comment: "How can organize this structure in Github that changes in the core module deployed automatically to mod1 and mod2?" - what do you mean by "deployed" here, exactly?

Comment: What I mean was that changing in the core repositories automatically bring into to mod1 and mod2.

Comment: There is no single right answer to this. You have the option of one repository, or multiple repositories, and if you go with multiple repositories, you have the option of using submodules, or doing something different. But which way to go is mostly a matter of opinion. You can ask specific technical questions *about* submodules, or Google's `repo` command, etc., and get solid answers, but everything else is just opinionated waffling (including my own opinions :-) ).

Comment: I think you are right. The trial with the submodule approach is not for me because it is kind of tricky with Github Actions but I am still looking for some answer to second question.

Answer (score 0):

> How can organize this structure in Github that changes in the core module deployed automatically to mod1 and mod2?

In github have 3 entirely different repositories and then combine these repositories in git via submodules.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/<user>/mod1 
git clone https://github.com/<user>/mod2
cd mod1
git submodule add https://github.com/<user>/core core
cd ..
cd mod2 
git submodule add https://github.com/<user>/core core
```

the github blog has instructions on how to work with submodules: https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/

Comment: Thanks for the submodule information. I tried it out with Github Actions and it is a bit of problematic. I think I will go with the one repo for all modules approach. But this still leaves the problem of managing the project. Because how can I keep the connection with main project and bring useful updates back and vice versa.